# Typescript map array of objects giving error: property '(property)' does not exist on type object

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code

I am using typescript in a React project and iterating through an array of objects to return components.

I am getting the expected result in the application with no errors in the console, but in VSCode I am getting this error: `Property 'amount' does not exist on type 'object'.` For every property that I am referencing in the map.

Here is the code snippet:

```
{recentHistory.map((item) => {
    if (item.type === 'ADD') {
        return <AddItem amount={item.amount} memo={item.memo} />
    } else if (item.type === 'SUBTRACT') {
        return <SubtractItem amount={item.amount} memo={item.memo} />
    }
})}
```

And a screenshot in VSCode.

[VSCode snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R57HX.png)

Again this is producing the expected output and works great, VSCode is just throwing these warnings.

Comment: How does `recentHistory` get defined and populated?

Comment: How is your recentHistory typed? It seems you're using the object type instead of defining a custom interface

Comment: The answer is always to fix it higher up.  Right now your `recentHistory` has type `object[]`.  If it has a correct type then you do not need to do anything inside of your `.map` callback.

Comment: Higher up the recentHistory is type object[], should it be something else?

Answer (score 1):

Define an interface for item of the form

```
interface Item {
  amount: number;
  memo: string;
  type: string;
}
```

Now, recentHistory is of type object array, you might have a code like this somewhere:

```
let recentHistory = [];
```

You need to change the declaration to hold array of type Item:

```
let recentHistory: Array<Item> = [];
```

credits: [Linda Paiste](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10431574/linda-paiste)

Comment: "Define an interface" is correct.  Assigning the type inside a callback is a bandaid solution to a problem that should be fixed higher up (in code that we haven't seen).  The `recentHistory` array should to be typed as `Item[]`.  It if is then the `item` will get type `Item` automatically.

Comment: Aah...I should not have answered so quickly. I'll edit it